How to Convert multiple rows into one (record) with comma as separator and line break at the end
I have the following two tables;
Index Table
Index ID  Index Value
111       Email
111       Phone
222       Customer
222       Advisor
333       E Mail
333       SMS

Export Table
ExportID  Index ID  Action    Action Time   
123        111     Export   30/07/2024 10:34
222        111     Export    30/07/2024 10:34
333        222     Export    30/07/2024 10:34
444        222     Export   30/07/2024 10:34

If I SELECT Index Value FROM Index Table when action is export, I get this result:
select
distinct 
stuff((
select  ','+ '"'+Index Value+'"' 
from [Index] I 
inner join Export E on I.IIndexD = E.IndexID 
where E.ID in('111','222,333')
and E. Action='Export'
for xml path('') ),1,1,'') 

I get this:
Email, Phone, Customer, Advisor ,Email ,SMS
but what I really need is one row with all the values separated by comma as one record and break line at the end and having second record below, like this:
1- Email, Phone, Customer
2- SMS, Email, Advisor
The actual result are:
"Email", "SMS", "Phone", "Email", "Customer", "Advisor"
However, giving that Email value and SMS are both from the same index ID, Phone and Email have also the same index ID and Customer and Advisor have the same index ID, What I need is to group the results by ExportTime or the export ID rather than the IndexID.
The desired results should be:
"Email", "Customer", "SMS" that's one row
"Phone", "Advisor", "Email" in a second row

Ssms is irrelevant, it's just the UI. What's select @@version

I don't understand your desired results. Please show us your actual desired results based on the sample data.

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)

You still need to show your actual desired result... Not just a description

Move the export table outside of the FOR XML thingy and only select from index inside it where index.ID = export.ID

since you want to print items with same index id's in separate rows
with values as (
    select
        Index,
        value,
        row_number() over (partition by Index over by value) as rn
    from
        records
   ),
     groupvalues as (
            select
              string_agg('"' || value || '"', ',')as values
            from
              values
            group by
                rn
            order by
               rn
  )
  select
    values
  from
   groupvalues;

